# Does $\mathbb{P}(X\in A, Y\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$ for all $A$ borel sets imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

> Is it true that if $\mathbb{P}(X\in A, Y\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$ for all $A$ borel sets then the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

My intuition says satisfying this condition will be not enough to imply independence but I can't think of any simple counter-example.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: I would like to prove/disprove a general case when we know nothing about the random variables.

Comment: @GEdgar **Come on!** Are you serious? The notion of (stochastic) independence is a part of every first course on probability. Would you ask for the definition of a *group*?

Comment: @GEdgar If you believe this, you have to find any first course stochastic textbook, open it, and check the definition again...

Comment: @GEdgar : $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff. $\mathbb{P}(X \in A, Y\in B) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all borel sets $A$ and $B$. And this is different from the question where we know only about one set. At least this was the definition in my book.

Comment: Question adjusted to avoid my problem in reading.

Comment: @GEdgar Bad idea. Next time you ask a question about groups, I should edit it likewise...

Comment: @Mateusz I believe three-valued random variables already provide a counterexample. You might want to check the case when $X$ and $Y$ arre $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$-valued and $$P(X=Y=k)=\frac19\qquad P(X=Y+1)=\frac19+\epsilon\qquad P(X=Y-1)=\frac19-\epsilon$$ for any $\epsilon$ in $(0,\frac19]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample.  The sample space has three points $a,b,c$.  Joint probabilities are as in the table:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a) = \frac{1}{9},\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=b) = \frac{2}{9},\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=c) = 0,\quad
\\
\mathbb{P}(X=b,Y=a) = 0,\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=b,Y=b) = \frac{1}{9},\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=b,Y=c) = \frac{2}{9},\quad
\\
\mathbb{P}(X=c,Y=a) = \frac{2}{9},\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=c,Y=b) = 0,\quad
\mathbb{P}(X=c,Y=c) = \frac{1}{9},\quad
$$